# JPG on server not visible

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, query-string, plesk

navigating to http://fciaao.org/images/FCIAAO_Logo.jpg returns the following error message in browser

`The system cannot find the file specified.`

however, if I type `?somevariable=mashthekeyboard` after the url, it works just fine.

http://fciaao.org/images/FCIAAO_Logo.jpg?somevariable=mashthekeyboard works

what is causing this?  It seems like it's a configuration in the site.  I've run fiddler, and without the querystring it reports just that the file is just "not there" with a 404.

### edit

This file was just uploaded yesterdayto the server. another file in the same directory loads fine.  I'm not sure when the working file was loaded.

Comment: If you are using apache, it is possible a mod_rewrite is in the way. Though, I don't know why it would be structured in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this site is hosted by this "Plesk" software. and it had hotlinking turned on which seems to work poorly. Turned off Hotlinking and it works fine now.